# Unix - Removing everything after a pattern using sed

Tags: sed

I  have a file which looks like below:

```
memory=500G
brand=HP
color=black
battery=5 hours
```

For every line, I want to remove everything after `=` and also the `=`.

Eventually, I want to get something like:

```
memory:brand:color:battery:
```

(All on one line with colons after every word)

Is there a one-line sed command that I can use?

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/=.\+\n\?/:/mg' /my/file
```

Adapted from [this fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/132382).

To be frank, however, I'd find something like this more readable:

```
cut -d = -f 1 /my/file | tr \\n :
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`:

```
awk -F= '{ printf "%s:", $1 } END { printf "\n" }' file.txt
```

Result:

```
memory:brand:color:battery:
```

If you don't want a colon after the last word, you can use `GNU sed` like this:

```
sed -n 's/=.*//; H; $ { g; s/\n//; s/\n/:/g; p }' file.txt
```

Result:

```
memory:brand:color:battery
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i ':a;$!N;s/=[^\n]*\n\?/:/;ta' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -F= -ane '{print $F[0].":"}' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
abc=def,100,200,dasdas
dasd=dsfsf,2312,123,
adasa=sdffs,1312,1231212,adsdasdasd
qeweqw=das,13123,13,asdadasds
dsadsaa=asdd,12312,123
> perl -F= -ane '{print $F[0].":"}' temp
abc:dasd:adasa:qeweqw:dsadsaa:
```

Answer (score 0):

My command is

First step:

sed 's/([a-z]+)(\=.*)/\1:/g' Filename |cat >a

cat a

memory:

brand:

color:

battery:

Second step:

sed -e 'N;s/\n//' a | sed -e 'N;s/\n//'

My output is

memory:brand:color:battery: